# Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу в C. Функция strcat

Tags: c, строки, указатели, char, malloc

Есть простой mp3-плеер:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *types = " type mpegvideo alias myFile";
char *open = "open ";

char* compound(char *path) {
    strcat(path, types);
    open = malloc(500);
    open = "open ";
    //printf(open);
    //printf("\n");
    //printf(path);
    strcat(open, path);
    return open;
}

void playMedia() {
    char *path = malloc(100);
    printf("Enter a path to your music: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    mciSendString(compound(path), NULL, 0, 0);
    mciSendString("play myFile wait", NULL, 0, 0);
    mciSendString("close myFile", NULL, 0, 0);

    if (getch() != 113) {
        open = "";
        path = "";
        playMedia();
    }
}

int main()
{
    playMedia();
    return 0;
}
```

И на этой строке `strcat(open, path);` возникает ошибка:

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x669EEA19 (ucrtbased.dll) в Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00C27B3D.
```

**Почему** возникает данная ошибка? **Как** её решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open = malloc(500);
```

Ага, теперь `open` указывает на специально выделенное место в памяти в 500 байт...

```
open = "open ";
```

А теперь - на место в памяти, где записано слово `open`...

```
strcat(open, path);
```

И теперь мы хотим дописать туда, где никто память не резервировал. А 500 байт теперь просто утечка...

Странно, что вы знаете про `strcat`, но не пытаетесь поступить верно и вместо `open = "open ";` написать `strcpy(open,"open ");`...

Comment: До того там даже и не доходит, ошибка происходит в первом `strcat(path, types)`. Массив `path` не инициализирован, поэтому  `strcat` в поисках конца строки вылетает за границу массива.

Comment: @freim Хм, а у меня ошибки нет. Только что исправил по совету Harry и код работает.

Comment: @True-hacker, это может работать пока массив инициализируется нулями, но ошибка-то все равно есть.

Comment: @freim Погодите... там в коде есть много ерунды, есть та же утечка памяти, словом, там еще работать и работать... но в `path` выполняется чтение - `scanf("%s", path);`, так что это получается вполне инициализированная строка.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я просмотрел scanf.